# Create a bat file that will run git and then run script

Tags: git, batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that when I run it will clone a repository locally.

To open the git I have the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

However no matter what command I put in after this it never runs.  I have read somewhere that this is because when you invoke a new shell it never returns to the old one, not sure how true this is, however is there a way for me to run git commands automatically after the git prompt window opens?

Edit:

So if I run this bat file, it wont echo my text, how come?  Why does it ignore all the commands after I open git.

```
"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\sh.exe" --login -i

ECHO THIS IS A TEST
```

Update:

When I run the above script, it opens a git shell, then if I type exit the echo command will run.  It is not until I have closed out my git shell that remainder of my batch script gets run.  How do I tell my batch script to execute commands within the git shell?

Comment: That is true, but does not apply here. Also, it should run the command just fine, although you don't need the new shell, so you can just execute the line `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`. Are you sure it doesn't execute anything? That seems odd. Can you start the script from CMD or add the line `pause` at the end of the script so you can read its output?

Comment: @GolezTrol I just edited the question and showed you my script.  What happens when I run that is a cmd window opens, starts git and it waits for my input, the "THIS IS A TEST" is not shown anywhere

Comment: Ah, yes. You start the git shell, which is a command line tool. Control is not returned to the batch file until the git shell is terminated. What exactly would you expect it to do?

Comment: I wanted a way to tell the new shell to run commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start an interactive shell (the `-i` option) it will not return until you exit the shell. To have commands run as part of your shell startup you then add them to the `/etc/profile` script. As you are dealing with the Git for Windows shell here that will be in the Git installation folder. You can also create a `$HOME/.profile` file that will be just for your user account. See the bash manual for more details about the files bash reads when starting an interactive session.